# Regular expression for complex numbers

Tags: python, regex, complex-numbers

So I'am trying to write regular expression for complex numbers (just as an exercise to study re module). But I can't get it to work. I want regex to match strings of form: '12+18j', '-14+45j', '54', '-87j' and so on. My attempt:

```
import re

num = r'[+-]?(?:\d*.\d+|\d+)'
complex_pattern = rf'(?:(?P<real>{num})|(?P<imag>{num}j))|(?:(?P=real)(?P=imag))'
complex_pattern = re.compile(complex_pattern)
```

But it doesn't really work as I want.

```
m = complex_pattern.fullmatch('1+12j')
m.groupdict()

Out[166]: {'real': None, 'imag': '1+12j'}
```

The reason behind its structure is the fact that I want input string to contain either real or imaginary part or both. And also to be able to extract real and imag groups from match object. There is other approach i tried and it seems to work except it catches empty strings (''):

```
complex_pattern = rf'(?P<real>{num})+(?P<imag>{num}j)+'
complex_pattern = re.compile(complex_pattern)
```

I guess I could implement check for empty string simply using if. But I'm interested in more pure way and to know why first implementation doesn't work as expected.

Comment: try using '\w' and not '\d'. This '\w' would match both characters and numbers

Comment: @Ade_1: What's the difference between a digit and a number?

Comment: @anubhava I want to be able to extract real and imag groups as well, not just match.

Comment: Then use: `\b(?:(?P<imag>[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)j)|(?P<real>[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)))\b`

Comment: It seems you used `(?P=real)(?P=imag)` thinking that it will match the Group "real" and "imag" *patterns* (in order not to repeat them), but in fact, these are backreferences to the values already captured with these groups. Also, why do you use `.fullmatch`? This method requires a full string match, and you seem to want to get separate numbers with groups, so you need `re.finditer`

Comment: Do you need something like https://ideone.com/VTiNSG? We can hardly help you because you did not show the expected output for the given sample input strings. Or, maybe you want https://ideone.com/EJQMcD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
import re
pattern = r'^(?!$)(?P<real>(?P<sign1>[+-]?)(?P<number1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?(?:(?P<imag>(?P<sign2>[+-]?)(?P<number2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?j)))?$'
texts = ['1+12j', '12+18j','-14+45j','54','-87j']
for text in texts:
    match = re.fullmatch(pattern, text)
    if match:
        print(text, '=>', match.groupdict())
    else:
        print(f'{text} did not match!')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EJQMcD). Output:

```py
1+12j => {'real': '1', 'sign1': '', 'number1': '1', 'imag': '+12j', 'sign2': '+', 'number2': '12j'}
12+18j => {'real': '12', 'sign1': '', 'number1': '12', 'imag': '+18j', 'sign2': '+', 'number2': '18j'}
-14+45j => {'real': '-14', 'sign1': '-', 'number1': '14', 'imag': '+45j', 'sign2': '+', 'number2': '45j'}
54 => {'real': '54', 'sign1': '', 'number1': '54', 'imag': None, 'sign2': None, 'number2': None}
-87j => {'real': '-8', 'sign1': '-', 'number1': '8', 'imag': '7j', 'sign2': '', 'number2': '7j'}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvvAPV/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!$)` - no end of string should follow at this position (no empty input is allowed)
- `(?P<real>(?P<sign1>[+-]?)(?P<number1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` - a "real" group:

  - `(?P<sign1>[+-]?)` - an optional `-` or `+` sign captured into Group "sign1"
  - `(?P<number1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits captured into Group "number1"
- `(?P<imag>(?P<sign2>[+-]?)(?P<number2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?j))?` - an optional sequence captured into "imag" group:

  - `(?P<sign2>[+-]?)` - an optional `-` or `+` sign captured into Group "sign2"
  - `(?P<number2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?j)` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits and then a `j` char captured into Group "number2"
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I wanted to add a solution which also allows basic scientific notation, and also use of i or j. I answer this only if other people came here like me to seek a regular expression which can find complex numbers, and for this key fact, a number with no imaginary part does not return as a match.

It deviates from the original question because of matching groups but could be changed, see commented out line with `cx_num_groups`.

This expression does not include matching groups for real and imaginary part because it allows for numbers such as 2j.

```
def _complex_re_gen():
    '''
    Because it is complicated, returns a string which returns a match with complex numbers.
    '''
    num = r'(?:[+\-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)'
    num_sci = r'(?:{num}(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?)'.format(num=num)
    cx_num = r'(?:{num_sci}?{num_sci}[ij])'.format(num_sci=num_sci)
    #cx_num_groups = cx_num = r'(?:(P<real>{num_sci})?(P<img>{num_sci}[ij])?)'.format(num_sci=num_sci)
    cx_match_wrapped= r"^(?:{cx_num}|\({cx_num}\))$".format(cx_num=cx_num)
    return cx_match_wrapped
```

With following test strings, this regexp returns a match for the commented ones:

```
cmplx_tests = [
        '1 + 2j'    , #no match
        '1e5-2e-2j' , #match
        'i2 +4j'    , #no match
        '1.25'      , #no match
        '-5-3.2i'   , #match
        '64.2-3.9j' , #match
    ]
```

This post was written in part because I wanted to solve a problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932392/3900445), with parsing complex arrays inside of parameter files.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for what you want?

```
import re
words= '+122+6766j'
pattern = re.compile(r'((^[-+]?(?P<real>\d+))?[-+]?(?P<img>\d{2,}j?\w)?)')
pattern.fullmatch(words).groupdict()
```

Output

```
{'real': '122', 'img': '6766j'}
```

Comment: Not really, because if I pass only real part (for example '12'), It doesn't' match at all. Plus I want sign to be included in groups.

Comment: I have adjusted it now. let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Even though I accepted [Wiktor Stribiżew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819954/16036013) answer and consider it really good. I have to add something that I noticed. Firstly, last string in `texts` list didn't grouped correctly (i.e. '-87j' -> real: -8; imag: 7j). To address this I propose following changes to simplified version of his answer:

```
import re

num = r'[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)'
pattern = rf'(?!$)(?P<real>{num}(?!\d))?(?P<imag>{num}j)?'

texts = ['1+12j', '12+18j','-14+45j','54','-87j']

for text in texts:
    match = re.fullmatch(pattern, text)
    if match:
        print(f'{text:>7} => {match.groupdict()}')
    else:
        print(f'{text:>7} did not match!')
```

Output:

```
1+12j   => {'real': '1', 'imag': '+12j'}
 12+18j => {'real': '12', 'imag': '+18j'}
-14+45j => {'real': '-14', 'imag': '+45j'}
     54 => {'real': '54', 'imag': None}
   -87j => {'real': None, 'imag': '-87j'}
```

The important diffrence here is adding `(?!\d)` to 'real' group of regex, to prevent strings like '-87j' to be splitted into '-8' and '7j'.