# Implicit resolvers and robust representers for human-friendly tuple and np.array support in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, numpy-ndarray, ruamel.yaml

I have a project where the user is expected to manually write a yaml file.
This yaml file might have some of its entries formatted as tuples or numpy arrays. We distinguish tuples and list internally in python to provide a convenient interface to the user, e.g. (1, 2, 3) is different than [1, 2, 3].

For convenience, I'd like the user to be able to enter a tuple directly using parenthesis, like so `name: (1,2,3)`. I'd also like the user to be able to provide with numpy arrays by entering something like `other_name: np.array([1,2,3])`. I know this won't preserve exact numerical accuracy of the numpy arrays, but we determined that this is a fair compromise for the improved user experience.

I'm using ruamel.yaml, mainly because it preserves comments.

I managed to do something that works, but it's does not feel "right" to me, especially the Resolving part. There's basically no implicit resolver and I'm using a dirty eval instead. I did manage to find some information about implicit resolvers in ruamel.yaml online, on SO, and by rummaging through the source, but I could not really make sense of it.

Here's a minimal working example, with comments pointing out where I feel like the implementation is not robust or unclean.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import ruamel.yaml


def _tupleRepresenter(dumper, data):
    # TODO: Make this more robust
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', str(data))


def _numpyRepresenter(dumper, data):
    # TODO: Make this more robust
    as_string = 'np.array(' + np.array2string(data, max_line_width=np.inf, precision=16, prefix='np.array(', separator=', ', suffix=')') + ')'
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', as_string)


def load_yaml(file):
    # TODO: Resolve tuples and arrays properly when loading
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.Representer.add_representer(tuple, _tupleRepresenter)
    yaml.Representer.add_representer(np.ndarray, _numpyRepresenter)
    return yaml.load(file)


def dump_yaml(data, file):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.Representer.add_representer(tuple, _tupleRepresenter)
    yaml.Representer.add_representer(np.ndarray, _numpyRepresenter)
    return yaml.dump(data, file)


yaml_file = """
test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
test_array: np.array([4,5,6])
"""

data = load_yaml(yaml_file)

data['test_tuple'] = eval(data['test_tuple']) # This feels dirty
data['test_array'] = eval(data['test_array']) # This feels dirty

dump_yaml(data, sys.stdout)
# test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
# test_array: np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

I welcome any help on improving this implementation with a proper implicit resolver, with robusts representers, and generally using ruamel.yaml more like it is intended to be.

---

**Update**:

With help from the comments, I managed to do something that works almost completely. Let's ignore that I'd need to write a proper non-eval parser for now.

The only issue left is that the new tags are now exported as strings, so they are not properly interpreted when reloading. They become strings instead and they won't survive many roundtrips.

How can I avoid that?

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import ruamel.yaml

# TODO: Replace evals by actual parsing
# TODO: Represent custom types without the string quotes

_tuple_re = "^(?:\((?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"
_array_re = "^(?:(np\.|)array\(\[(?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\]\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"
_complex_re = "^(?:(?:\d+(?:(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+\-]\d+)?)?)?(?: *[+\-] *))?(?:\d+(?:(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+\-]\d+)?)?)?[jJ]$"


def _tuple_constructor(self, node):
    return eval(self.construct_scalar(node))


def _array_constructor(self, node):
    value = node.value
    if not value.startswith('np.'):
        value = 'np.' + value
    return eval(value)


def _complex_constructor(self, node):
    return eval(node.value)


def _tuple_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', str(data))


def _array_representer(dumper, data):
    as_string = 'np.array(' + np.array2string(data, max_line_width=np.inf, precision=16, prefix='np.array(', separator=', ', suffix=')') + ')'
    as_string = as_string.replace(' ', '').replace(',', ', ')
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', as_string)


def _complex_representer(dumper, data):
    repr = str(data).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', repr)


custom_types = {
    '!tuple':   {'re':_tuple_re,   'constructor': _tuple_constructor,   'representer':_tuple_representer,   'type': tuple,      'first':list('(')             },
    '!nparray': {'re':_array_re,   'constructor': _array_constructor,   'representer':_array_representer,   'type': np.ndarray, 'first':list('an')            },
    '!complex': {'re':_complex_re, 'constructor': _complex_constructor, 'representer':_complex_representer, 'type': complex,    'first':list('0123456789+-jJ')},
}


def load_yaml(file):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    for tag,ct in custom_types.items():
        yaml.Constructor.add_constructor(tag, ct['constructor'])
        yaml.Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(tag, ruamel.yaml.util.RegExp(ct['re']), ct['first'])
        yaml.Representer.add_representer(ct['type'], ct['representer'])
    return yaml.load(file)


def dump_yaml(data, file):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    for tag,ct in custom_types.items():
        yaml.Constructor.add_constructor(tag, ct['constructor'])
        yaml.Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(tag, ruamel.yaml.util.RegExp(ct['re']), ct['first'])
        yaml.Representer.add_representer(ct['type'], ct['representer'])
    return yaml.dump(data, file)

yaml_file = """
test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
test_array: array([4.0,5+0j,6.0j])
test_complex: 3 + 2j
"""

data = load_yaml(yaml_file)

dump_yaml(data, sys.stdout)
# test_tuple: '(1, 2, 3)'
# test_array: 'np.array([4.+0.j, 5.+0.j, 0.+6.j])'
# test_complex: '3+2j'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Anthon in the comments, and reading through his ruamel.yaml source, I managed to answer my question.

I'm putting a minimum viable solution here for reference.
It'd probably be a good idea to replace the evals with an actual parser to avoid exploits if this is ever to be executed on a yaml file form a source you don't trust.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import ruamel.yaml

from ruamel.yaml.comments import TaggedScalar

# TODO: Replace evals by actual parsing

_tuple_re = "^(?:\((?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"
_array_re = "^(?:(np\.|)array\(\[(?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\]\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"


def _tuple_constructor(self, node):
    return eval(self.construct_scalar(node))


def _array_constructor(self, node):
    value = node.value
    if not value.startswith('np.'):
        value = 'np.' + value
    return eval(value)


def _tuple_representer(dumper, data):
    repr = str(data)
    return dumper.represent_tagged_scalar(TaggedScalar(repr, style=None, tag='!tuple'))


def _array_representer(dumper, data):
    repr = 'np.array(' + np.array2string(data, max_line_width=np.inf, precision=16, prefix='np.array(', separator=', ', suffix=')') + ')'
    repr = repr.replace(' ', '').replace(',', ', ')
    return dumper.represent_tagged_scalar(TaggedScalar(repr, style=None, tag='!nparray'))


custom_types = {
    '!tuple':   {'re':_tuple_re,   'constructor': _tuple_constructor,   'representer':_tuple_representer,   'type': tuple,      'first':list('(')             },
    '!nparray': {'re':_array_re,   'constructor': _array_constructor,   'representer':_array_representer,   'type': np.ndarray, 'first':list('an')            },
}


def load_yaml(file):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    for tag,ct in custom_types.items():
        yaml.Constructor.add_constructor(tag, ct['constructor'])
        yaml.Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(tag, ruamel.yaml.util.RegExp(ct['re']), ct['first'])
        yaml.Representer.add_representer(ct['type'], ct['representer'])
    return yaml.load(file)


def dump_yaml(data, file):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    for tag,ct in custom_types.items():
        yaml.Constructor.add_constructor(tag, ct['constructor'])
        yaml.Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(tag, ruamel.yaml.util.RegExp(ct['re']), ct['first'])
        yaml.Representer.add_representer(ct['type'], ct['representer'])
    return yaml.dump(data, file)

yaml_file = """
test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
test_array: array([4.0,5+0j,6.0j])
"""

data = load_yaml(yaml_file)

dump_yaml(data, sys.stdout)
# test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
# test_array: np.array([4.+0.j, 5.+0.j, 0.+6.j])
```

Answer (score 1):

A representer in `ruamel.yaml` is used to dump a Python type in a specific way as YAML, you cannot normally use it to create a Python type from some part of YAML. For the latter you need a constructor.

A constructor can be explicit, using a tag ( e.g. `!!float`, a list of these can be found [here](https://yaml.org/type/) ), or implicit, i.e. recognise the input which in `ruamel.yaml` is done on scalars initiallly using regular expressions.

Your example seems to border on the need of expanding the collection types of YAML beyond the mapping and dict and I don't think you will succeed without rewriting most of the `ruamel.yaml` code. What I do recommend is that you write the code construct your numpy array from tagged input like the following first:

```
test_tuple: !np.array [1, 2, 3]
```

even though you don't want your users to write things that way. And also dump numpy arrays using that tag.

The next step would then to write a constructor that matches scalars that start and end with a opening and closing parenthesis, or start with `np.array([` and end in `])` (even though there is a `[` in there this doesn't start a sequence when in the middle of a scalar. You should keep track of which of the two formats was used to construct the NumPy array (e.g. using some unique attribute that has a tri-state for tagged-, parenthesis-, or np.array- input). You will need to parse the matching scalar, but you don't need to do that using `eval()`. For altneratives, look e.g. at the processing of `!timestamp`. Although your examples only have an array of integers, you might want to look at (also) accepting floats.

Once you have those additional non-tagged constructors, you can adapt the representer for the NumPy array to use the non-tagged formats depending on the attribute.

A good example for the above are the round-trip processing of floats (preserving scientific notation) and the aforementioned timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you point me to an example or documentation for the constructor that matches a custom pattern (for the implicit resolver)? I did find some examples in the source, but whenever I tried to reproduce it it just seemed not to be used.

Comment: There are no examples beyond adding the tagged version that do this except for the source code itself. You also have to realise that the non-quoted string (with or without `np.array()`, has limitations that a sequence wouldn't have e.g. wrt the use of spaces, newlines, nesting, etc. It would be better to have your users actually provide that tag, so you are more flexible and you can  the parser to do the rest of the job, support multi-dimensional arraya, different integer and float representations etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the source and come back here if I have questions, or to post my answer. Is it better to extend the instantiated "yaml" object or work directly in the class? I only had success with the insurance so far. I have no issue in supporting a strict format for the tuple, and arrays could be lists, but I just realized I'd also need to support complex numbers.

Comment: I updated my question with the modifications I did following this discussion.
I feel like I'm very close to have it work 100%, but the new types are always dumped with as a string quotes, which breaks round-tripping. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I do think I managed to figure it out using `TaggedScalar`, I'll post an answer in a few days when I confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand on the provided solution by adding a way that does not use `eval()`. It also probably fails in some cases, and could probably do with using the `tolist()` method of numpy arrays for the dumping.

The basic method of avoiding `eval()` is for the constructor to parse the internals of the call to array or tuple as a list. Once it's in a list-like form, then the ruamel.yaml parser can try to load the item as a list. Then, a call to `np.array()` or `tuple()` can make the object into what we desire.

Added here is a complex number regular expression, constructor, and representer, necessary so that yaml can itself load the internals of the numpy array as a list, so that it has support for lists of complex numbers.

Some slight cosmetic change in the load and dump functions also happened.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import ruamel.yaml
import re

from ruamel.yaml.comments import TaggedScalar

def _complex_re_gen():
    '''
    Because it is complicated, returns a string which parses complex expressions.
    # Gave up and looked for complex number regular expression,
    #   modified to include scientific numbers. 
    # See https://web.archive.org/web/20221228150825/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818976/regular-expression-for-complex-numbers
    '''
    num = r'(?:[+\-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)'
    num_sci = r'(?:{num}(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?)'.format(num=num)
    cx_num = r'(?:{num_sci}?{num_sci}[ij])'.format(num_sci=num_sci)
    cx_match_wrapped= r"^(?:{cx_num}|\({cx_num}\))$".format(cx_num=cx_num)
    return cx_match_wrapped
_tuple_re = r"^(?:\((?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"
_array_re = r"^(?:(np\.|)array\(\[(?:.|\n|\r)*,(?:.|\n|\r)*\]\){1}(?: |\n|\r)*$)"
_complex_re= _complex_re_gen()

# def _tuple_constructor(self, node):
#    return eval(self.construct_scalar(node))

def _tuple_constructor_safe(self,node):
    value = node.value
    value = re.sub("^\(","[",value)
    value = re.sub("\)$","]",value)
    safe_l = yaml_load(value,yaml=None)
    return tuple(safe_l)


def _complex_constructor(self,node):
    return complex(node.value)

def _array_constructor_safe(self,node):
    value = node.value
    value = re.sub("^(?:np\.|)array\(","",value)
    value = re.sub("\)$","",value)
    safe_l = yaml_load(value,yaml=None)
    return np.array(safe_l)


def _tuple_representer(dumper, data):
    repr = str(data)
    return dumper.represent_tagged_scalar(TaggedScalar(repr, style=None, tag='!tuple'))

def _complex_representer(dumper,data):
    repr = str(data)
    repr = re.sub("()","",repr)
    return dumper.represent_tagged_scalar(TaggedScalar(repr, style=None, tag='!complex'))

def _array_representer(dumper, data):
    repr = 'np.array(' + np.array2string(data, max_line_width=np.inf, precision=16, prefix='np.array(', separator=', ', suffix=')') + ')'
    repr = repr.replace(' ', '').replace(',', ', ')
    return dumper.represent_tagged_scalar(TaggedScalar(repr, style=None, tag='!nparray'))
    
def _complex_resolver(str_resolve,match_re = re.compile(r'[ij]')):
    '''
    For debugging. Sees if the built-in complex constructor allows it.
    '''
    if re.search(match_re,str_resolve):
        try:
            cplx = complex(str_resolve.replace('i','j'))
            return cplx
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None


custom_types = {
    '!tuple':   {'re':_tuple_re,   'constructor': _tuple_constructor_safe,   'representer':_tuple_representer,   'type': tuple,      'first':list('(')             },
    '!nparray': {'re':_array_re,   'constructor': _array_constructor_safe,   'representer':_array_representer,   'type': np.ndarray, 'first':list('an')},
    '!complex': {'re':_complex_re,   'constructor': _complex_constructor,   'representer':_complex_representer,   'type': complex, 'first':None }
}



def yaml_add_custom_types(yaml,custom_types):
    for tag,ct in custom_types.items():
            yaml.Constructor.add_constructor(tag, ct['constructor'])
            yaml.Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(tag, ruamel.yaml.util.RegExp(ct['re']), ct['first'])
            yaml.Representer.add_representer(ct['type'], ct['representer'])
    
def setup_yaml(yaml,custom_types):
    yaml_add_custom_types(yaml,custom_types)


yaml = yaml_preset = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
def yaml_load(fin,yaml = yaml_preset, custom_setup=True):
    '''
    Assumes globally setup yaml is used. 
    If we want to start from scratch and configure new YAML instance,
        we set yaml=None. custom_setup 
        then will setup yaml to deal with custom types
    '''
    if yaml is None:
        yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    if custom_setup:
        setup_yaml(yaml,custom_types)
    return yaml.load(fin)

def yaml_dump(obj,fout, yaml= yaml_preset,custom_setup=True):
    '''
    Assumes globally setup yaml is used. 
    If we want to start from scratch and configure new YAML instance,
        we set yaml=None. custom_setup 
        then will setup yaml to deal with custom types
    
    '''
    if yaml is None:
        yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    if custom_setup:
        setup_yaml(yaml,custom_types)
    return yaml.dump(obj,fout)
    
setup_yaml(yaml,custom_types)



yaml_file = """
test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
test_array: array([4.0,5+0j,6.0j])
"""

data = yaml_load(yaml_file)

yaml_dump(data, sys.stdout)
# test_tuple: (1, 2, 3)
# test_array: np.array([4.+0.j, 5.+0.j, 0.+6.j])
```

To highlight the new solving method more effectively, I'll explain one constructor more in detail:

```
def _tuple_constructor_safe(self,node):
    value = node.value
    value = re.sub("^\(","[",value)
    value = re.sub("\)$","]",value)
    safe_l = yaml_load(value,yaml=None)
    return tuple(safe_l)
```

We alter the value of the string we parse so that it has brackets which wrap it. This makes it a YAML list. Then, we load the YAML list using yaml. One crucial thing is that we must make a new YAML object, as the YAML object which is currently loading the list is otherwise in an invalid state to load another object.

Comment: After posting this answer, I got some strange behavior in parsing the tuple. I'm looking into it.

Comment: The solution now works again.

Comment: This does seem like an elegant approach, I saved it for later reference. Thanks!

Comment: You got me most of the way there!